# OCMod offset not replacing multiple lines of code

Tags: xml, opencart, opencart-3, ocmod

I am new to OCMod and trying to tidy up my Opencart 3.x store modifications. In many places I need to replace multiple lines of code and I can't seem to get offset to work. Following Digicart's solution: [Replace admin TPL files with OCMOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121695/replace-admin-tpl-files-with-ocmod)
I have the following code.

3 LINES OF CODE TO REPLACE:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
```

OCMod CODE:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig" name="">
<operation info="Move and change add to cart icon and remove text">
<search offset="3"><![CDATA[<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>]]></search>
    <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
            {% if 1 %}
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>              
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Cart" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            {% endif %}
    ]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
```

Please ignore the redundant "if", actual conditions are removed for testing. The problem is that offset="3" appears to be totally ignored and only the search string is replaced. I end up with 5 buttons instead of 3 re-ordered and modified buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please move `offset` to `add` tag and use 2 instead of 3 (starting from zero):

```
<add position="replace" offset="2">
```

I tested with OpenCart 3.0.2.0 and it worked.

For a quicker check, you can upload your file with `install.ocmod.xml` name in the `system/` folder, and then clear the `ocmod` cache.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
  <name>test123456</name>
  <code>test123456</code>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <author>test123456</author>
  <link>http://www.opencart.com</link>
<file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig" name="">
<operation info="Move and change add to cart icon and remove text">
<search><![CDATA[<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>]]></search>
    <add position="replace" offset="2"><![CDATA[
            {% if 1 %}
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>              
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Cart" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            {% endif %}
    ]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
</modification>
```

Comment: As it is often impossible to search unique strings in exactly the beginning of the code to be modified, and multi-line search does not work. Do you happen to know if <add position="xxx" offset="-X"> will work to replace text above the search string? Also can the offset argument be used with the search tag to go to the nth occurrence of a non-unique search string? Sorry, you did answer the original question, it's just left me searching for more ways to control ocmod and there just isn't much information available.

Comment: Yes you can use `offset`. Now I can not exactly remember that you should use `offset` in the `search` tag or in the `add` tag, but I'm sure you can use `offset`.